# How to perform blind deblurring in CPP in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, deconvolution

What steps should I follow to deblur an image?  I looked into it and found I have to know some PSF's. The formulae for all these are very complex and are already inbuilt in MATLAB. But I want to do the same manually in CPP.

Input is just the blurred image. I need to estimate and optimise the PSF as well.

Comment: First identify the method used in MATLAB.

Comment: There are some cases where the point spread function is already known. Could you clarify what your case is?

Comment: @Nivii1406 No i , dont know the PSF as well. Edited the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did peek a look at them, but but couldnt figure out still how to do the calculations in cpp

Comment: @VaibhavSetia: so please name that method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If i can know first of all how i can create the PSF in CPP

Comment: @VaibhavSetia: you didn't answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I couldnt quite get your question.The method iteratively finds an optimal PSF , using which if we doconvolve the image we can get the original image.

Comment: @VaibhavSetia: I am asking you the name of the particular method.